# Parsing advanced XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I currently have a 1.6mb XML file which I'm having much trouble logically wrapping my head around.

The format is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<imgdir name="Map.img">
    <imgdir name="3rd">
        <imgdir name="300000000">
            <string name="streetName" value="Ellin Forest"/>
            <string name="mapName" value="Altaire Camp"/>
        </imgdir>
    </imgdir>
    <imgdir name="4th">
        <imgdir name="400000000">
            <string name="streetName" value="asd"/>
            <string name="mapName" value="yolo"/>
        </imgdir>
    </imgdir>
</imgdir>
```

I want to access the mapName property within a given imgdir with a numeral value, as in 300000000 would return "Altaire Camp".

I have tried quite a bit of code to make this work, and I haven't even come close. I even tried something the lines of $xml->xpath('//300000000') to see if I could get access to the string child with the name mapName through that, but to no success.

I have also tried this:

```
if (file_exists('Map.xml')) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('Map.xml');

    foreach ($xml->imgdir as $imgdir) 
    {
        echo $imgdir["name"] . "\n";
    }
}
```

Which return 3rd, 4th, and so on.
I can't seem to actually get the string name="mapName" with anything I do.

Edit:
Thanks guys, I went with this solution:

```
function GetMapNameByID($id)
{
    if (file_exists('Map.xml')) 
    {
        $xml = simplexml_load_file('Map.xml');

        $nodes = $xml->xpath("//imgdir[@name='$id']");

        foreach($nodes as $node) 
        {
            return $node->string[1]["value"];
        }
    }
}
```

Which returns exactly the value I want.

Comment: It's an [attribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) that you're trying to access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xpath is wrong.  You need to use

```
$xml->xpath("//imgdir[@name='300000000']/string[@name='mapName']/@value")[0];
```

This will first select the *imgdir* element with a name attribute equal to **300000000**, no matter how deep it occurs.  Then it selects the *string* child of that with a name attribute equal to **mapName**, and finally selects the *value* attribute of that *string*.

Finally, we pull off the first element of the array returned, which will be the value that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
$xmlstr = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<imgdir name="Map.img">
  <imgdir name="3rd">
    <imgdir name="300000000">
      <string name="streetName" value="Ellin Forest"/>
      <string name="mapName" value="Altaire Camp"/>
    </imgdir>
  </imgdir>
  <imgdir name="4th">
    <imgdir name="400000000">
      <string name="streetName" value="asd"/>
      <string name="mapName" value="yolo"/>
    </imgdir>
  </imgdir>
</imgdir>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
foreach ($xml->imgdir as $imgdir) {
  echo '<div>Directory Name = ' . $imgdir->imgdir['name'] . '</div>';
  echo '<div>mapName = ' . $imgdir->imgdir->string[1]['value'] . '</div>';
}
```